# How to get the duration of a video from the Azure media services?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, azure-media-services

I'm using the Windows Azure Media Services .NET SDK 3 to make use of the streaming services. I want to retrieve the duration of the video. How can I retrieve the duration of a video using the Windows Azure Media Services .NET SDK 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure creates some metadata files (xml) which could be queried for the duration. These files be accessed using the media-service extension

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services-extensions

Under Get Assets Meta Data:

```
// The asset encoded with the Windows Media Services Encoder. Get a reference to it from the context.
IAsset asset = null;

// Get a SAS locator for the asset (make sure to create one first).
ILocator sasLocator = asset.Locators.Where(l => l.Type == LocatorType.Sas).First();

// Get one of the asset files.
IAssetFile assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.ToList().Where(af => af.Name.EndsWith(".mp4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).First();

// Get the metadata for the asset file.
AssetFileMetadata manifestAssetFile = assetFile.GetMetadata(sasLocator);

TimeSpan videoDuration = manifestAssetFile.Duration;
```

Comment: This appears to not work anymore with the latest api and I cannot figure out how to get to the meta data any more. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, however `assetFile.GetMetadata()` returns a `IEnumerable<AssetFileMetadata>` (at least in v4.2.0), and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AMSv3, the AdaptiveStreaming job generates a `video_manifest.json` file in the output asset. You can parse that to get the duration. Here's an example:

```cs
public async Task<TimeSpan> GetVideoDurationAsync(string encodedAssetName)
{
    var encodedAsset = await ams.Assets.GetAsync(config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, encodedAssetName);
    if(encodedAsset is null) throw new ArgumentException("An asset with that name doesn't exist.", nameof(encodedAssetName));
    var sas = GetSasForAssetFile("video_manifest.json", encodedAsset, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2));
    var responseMessage = await http.GetAsync(sas);
    var manifest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Amsv3Manifest>(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    var duration = manifest.AssetFile.First().Duration;
    return XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(duration);
}
```

For the `Amsv3Manifest` model and a sample `video_manifest.json` file, see: https://app.quicktype.io/?share=pAhTMFSa3HVzInAET5k4

You may use the following definition of `GetSasForAssetFile()` to get started:

```cs
private string GetSasForAssetFile(string filename, Asset asset, DateTime expiry)
{
    var client = GetCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference(asset.Container);
    var blob = container.GetBlobReference(filename);

    var offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
    {
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(offset),
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = expiry.Add(offset),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
    };
    var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
    return $"{blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri}{sas}";
}

private CloudBlobClient GetCloudBlobClient()
{
    if(CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConfig.ConnectionString, out var storageAccount) is false)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(message: "The storage configuration has an invalid connection string.", paramName: nameof(config));
    }

    return storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Media Services SDK, we only provides the size of asset through contentFileSize (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974275.aspx). However, we don't provide metadata of video (such as duration). When you get a streaming locator, the play would tell how long the video asset would be.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: You used to provide the duration until the most recent update of the api. Where did this go?

Answer (score 0):

@galdin got me halfway there with their answer. Since a few things have changed, I wanted to add a quick example for using Azure storage v12. Also, I grabbed the SAS for the container and read the manifest from there; it seemed a bit easier. For my purposes, I needed the total minutes.

You can quickly create an `Amsv3Manifest` model by copying the manifest JSON data and using the paste special option in Visual Studio.

```cs
//todo: get duration from _manifest.json
HttpResponseMessage? responseMessage = null;
var roundedMinutes = 0;

// Use Media Services API to get back a response that contains
// SAS URL for the Asset container into which to upload blobs.
// That is where you would specify read-write permissions 
// and the expiration time for the SAS URL.
var durationAssetContainerSas = await _client.Assets.ListContainerSasAsync(
    config.ResourceGroup,
    config.AccountName,
    assetName,
    permissions: AssetContainerPermission.ReadWrite,
    expiryTime: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).ToUniversalTime());

var durationSasUri = new Uri(durationAssetContainerSas.AssetContainerSasUrls.First());

// Use Storage API to get a reference to the Asset container via
// Sas and then access the manifest file in the container.
// the manifest file starts with 32 characters from the video name
BlobContainerClient durBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(durationSasUri);
BlobClient durationBlobClient = durBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient($"{name[..32]}_manifest.json");

try
{
    responseMessage = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(durationBlobClient.Uri);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.LogError(e.Message);
}

if (responseMessage != null)
{
    var manifest = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Amsv3Manifest>(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    var playDuration = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(manifest.AssetFile.First().Duration);
    roundedMinutes = (int)Math.Round(playDuration.TotalMinutes);
}
```