# Azure media service delete file

Tags: azure-media-services

i try delete file in media service, with this code but it is not working(nothing happen) :

```
CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaServicesAccountName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaServicesAccountKey"]);

IAsset asset = context.Assets.First();


ILocator sasLocator = asset.Locators.Where(l => l.Type == LocatorType.Sas).First();


IAssetFile assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.ToList().First();

assetFile.Delete();
```

I used this code as an example : 
[How to get the duration of a video from the Azure media services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296205/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-from-the-azure-media-services/29348192#29348192)

I think my problem is due to "locators" I do not understand how to create and manipulated.

Comment: what do you mean (nothing happen)? Are you getting any exception? If not , after you re-query asset does it have same set of files?

Comment: I have no error and the file is no delete.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is much simpler ...
We did not need use "Locators" for this, for found a video :

```
IAsset GetAsset(string name)
{ 
    var assets = _context.Assets.Where(a => a.Name == name).ToList();
    if (!assets.Any())
    {
        //no video found
    }
    return assets.First();
}
```

and you can delete :

```
GetAsset("test-video").Delete();
```

Comment: you will have reference to object after delete, but you should not find this asset after requerying it by id.
var iD="someId";

var asset = _context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id== Id).FirstorDefault();
if(asset){ asset.Delete();Console.WriteLine("Deleted"); }
asset = _context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id== Id).FirstorDefault();
if(asset){Console.WriteLine("Should not enter here");}